# Does the "discussion board" application send a invitation to every team member?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, discussion-board, classic-experience

I recently had a unfortunate experience when adding Yammer to our company Intranet in SharePoint Online.

After creating a new discussion, a invitation had been sent to everyone in the company. I want to prevent this at any cost.

Now I do again need a discussion platform, but this time with the old school application "discussion board" from the app list.

Does anyone know if this application will send a invitation mail to every employee again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **No**.

If you are creating a classic **Discussion Board** app in SharePoint, it will not send any invitation/email to site users.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sadly I just saw they removed the disscusion board from the classical store. Last week it still existed.